# How to perform mouse actions Mouse move source webelement--> clickAndHold --> mouse move destination element with selenium4 webdriver.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to perform below step for my senario.

1. Move mouse pointer to source webelement
2. Mouse click And hold on source webelement
3. move mouse pointer to another destination webelement.

In selenium 4 "mouseDown" & "mouseMove" function are deprecated. And i tried below option to perform click and hold and move from source to destination webelement.

1. driver.actions({ async: true}).move({ origin: sourceElement }).press().move({ origin: middleElement }).move({ origin: destinationElement }).release().perform()
2. driver.actions({bridge: true}).move({duration: 2000,
   x: sourceLocation.x, y:sourceLocation.y}).press().
   move({ duration: 1000,
   x: destinationLocation.x, y:destinationLocation.y}).release().perform()
3. driver.actions().move({ origin: sourceElement }).press().perform();
   await FWL.UTIL_think(4)
   await act.move({ origin: destinationElement }).release().perform()
4. driver.actions().dragAndDrop(sourceElement,destinationElement)

All the above option didn't worked for me.
Can anyone help me to get javascript code or another options to perform mouse "Click and hold" and move to destination webelement.

Comment: You might try dragAndDropBy: actions.dragAndDropBy(element, xtarget, ytarget).build().perform();  If the DOM is expecting certain events, though... I think it's ondragstart, on dragend?... you need to use a custom script for generating those events.